# Printing Backtrace/Stacktrace

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

I have tried many ways to print stacktrace / backtrace in MinGW 64 - but it seems that it is not possible anyway.

Seems like backtrace library and its required includes / compiler flags are not available in MinGW - inclusion of execinfo.h states error and so is compiler flag -rdynamic .

Please let me know a clean method to generate a backtrace stack of a function - it would better if there is no external dependency is there but if required we can make use as there is no such other mechanism

---------------------------------UPDATED---------------------------------------

As per suggestion I tried a program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
     unsigned int   i;
     void         * stack[ 100 ];
     unsigned short frames;
     SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
     HANDLE         process;

     process = GetCurrentProcess();

     SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );

     frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
     symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
     symbol->MaxNameLen   = 255;
     symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );

     for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ )
     {
         SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );

         printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
     }

     free( symbol );
}
```

I get the below compilation error - I know I am missing some headers but which one I am not sure:

```
$ /c/tools/mingw64/bin/c++ test27.cpp
test27.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test27.cpp:8:6: error: 'SYMBOL_INFO' was not declared in this scope
      SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
      ^
test27.cpp:8:21: error: 'symbol' was not declared in this scope
      SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
                     ^
test27.cpp:9:6: error: 'HANDLE' was not declared in this scope
      HANDLE         process;
      ^
test27.cpp:11:6: error: 'process' was not declared in this scope
      process = GetCurrentProcess();
      ^
test27.cpp:11:34: error: 'GetCurrentProcess' was not declared in this scope
      process = GetCurrentProcess();
                                  ^
test27.cpp:13:36: error: 'TRUE' was not declared in this scope
      SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );
                                    ^
test27.cpp:13:41: error: 'SymInitialize' was not declared in this scope
      SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );
                                         ^
test27.cpp:15:72: error: 'CaptureStackBackTrace' was not declared in this scope
      frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
                                                                        ^
test27.cpp:16:45: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
      symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
                                             ^
test27.cpp:22:34: error: 'DWORD64' was not declared in this scope
          SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );
                                  ^
test27.cpp:22:69: error: 'SymFromAddr' was not declared in this scope
          SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );
                                                                     ^
test27.cpp:27:19: error: 'free' was not declared in this scope
      free( symbol );
                   ^
```

Comment: Did you try [CaptureStackBackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: No It is an Embedded C++ application - I am not sure of this API - can we code Windows API and compile using MinGW? Is there an example usage?

Comment: I'm confused, do you use a mingw compiler, or something for embedded development. AFAIK they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes we make use of mingw compiler - we make sure that the code can be later compiled in Linux OS however the one that goes into the board is from Xilink ones